# Nested iterator in wso2 esb skipping all the sequence after completion of second iterator

Tags: iterator, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a situation in my current assignment , I have some `xlx` files in a ftp server, I am reading it one by one in my first iterator in a proxy service. Inside this iterator I am splitting this `xlx` file into some `csv` files and again **running a iterator(Inside the first iterator**) to read it and do some validation & transformation on the top of it using smooks and `XSLT` transformer mediator. Now the issue is once the second iterator completes proxy service is skipping all the other sequence that are there in the first iterator and the outside the first iterator  and just getting stopped after the second iterator.

Please help me out , is it wso2 esb expected behavior or i am doing some this wrong in my configuration? i googled a lot related to this but not found any solution .

Comment: Can you please share the config of your proxy service?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the same for a different use case. I wasn't runnning into any issues, so it looks for me like there must be something missing in your configuration.

```
// first iterator
<iterate xmlns:sfdc="http://wso2.org/salesforce/adaptor"
              continueParent="true"
              expression="//sfdc:iterator">
                  <target>
                     //second interator
                      <sequence>
                           <iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                               xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                       xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com"
                       continueParent="true"
                       expression="//*[local-name() = 'queryMoreResponse']/*[local-name() = 'result']/*[local-name() = 'records']">
                       //do something
                      </iterate>
```

Hope that helps.